# I have the runscope api monitoring resources. I created these resources by using terraform. How can I cleanup these runscope services?

Tags: terraform, runscope

I created runscope api monitoring resources by using terraform. I want to cleanup those by using terraform.

```
resource "runscope_test" "api" {
    name        = "api-test"
    description = "checks the api is up and running"
    bucket_id   = runscope_bucket.main.id
}
```

Comment: If you mean by clean up deleting this resource previously created by Terraform, you can execute `terraform destroy`. See documentation https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/destroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use terraform [destory](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/destroy) or if you want to be more specific, use [-target](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/state/resource-targeting) option:

```
terraform destroy -target="runscope_test.api"
```